# Unable to sqoop the data from sql(oracle)

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import a table from oracle to hdfs(hive table). But I am unable to complete the import. Here's the command I'm using :

`sqoop import --hive-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/servicename --table sql_schema.table --username uname --password pwd --hive-table hive_schema.table --num-mappers 1 --verbose`

Here's the error I'm encountering

```
15/10/12 15:17:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/10/12 15:17:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1444407202506_0022_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:165)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:213)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
        ... 23 more
```

I tried connecting to oracle from the same machine and I was successful and able to access the tables from the servers but I'm not sure why I see this **IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection** error.

Any help in this regards is much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your datanode's/nodemanager's are also able to connect to Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved ! The problem was with the DSCP markings. Once the DSCP markings are enabled to all the datanodes, the connection was successfully established !

Comment: what are DSCP markings? and how to activate them in all datanodes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can access the db from the server you are trying sqoop command?

Are you able to ping thr oracle hostnsme on that port no?

I got the same problem last week.my problem is that port no that oracle is running is blocked on gateway node of hadoop cluster.